# Does Spring webflux supports socket.io or sockJs

Tags: spring, socket.io, spring-webflux, sockjs

Following spring webflux documentation
I couldnt but notice that every single example is based on pure websocket.

Does spring webflux supports such browser client libraries such as socket.io or sockjs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spring Framework team is not considering this feature right now in WebFlux. Because of the back-pressure support in reactive streams, the team is considering protocols that would leverage that information.

For example, rsocket support would fit that space and much more. See [SPR-16751](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16751)

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this subject!

Comment: I'm able to use plain ol' WebSockets with Spring WebFlux, but not socket.io. When I try to use socket.io, I get an "Invalid 'Upgrade' header:" error. I found this issue where it happens on spring cloud gateway. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/209 It'd be awesome if socket.io could be used with Spring WebFlux WebSockets.

Comment: @brian-clozel Isn't RSocket is a transport-independent **application level protocol**? It's more like replacement of STOMP from Spring MVC's WebSocket support, but it doesn't replace sock.js, wich is abstraction and indirection layer of **transport level protocol** (it can simulate WebSocket where it is not supported). So, sock.js is required anyway, no matter what application level protocol will be chosen, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. RSocket libraries ship with transport level protocol support as well. For example, the Rsocket JavaScript library supports websocket with browsers. Depending on the target environment, only a subset of transport protocols might be available.